# RadioButtonFor not bind null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, 1, Model.LivStato == 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, -1, Convert.ToString(Model.LivStato) == string.Empty)
```

If `Model.LivStato == 1` is true, the radio button is checked.

I don't understand why if `Convert.ToString(Model.LivStato) == string.Empty` is true, the radio button is not checked

I also try this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, -1, !Model.LivStato.HasValue)
```

but don't work.

In the model:

```
public short? LivStato { get; set; }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `HtmlHelper.RadioButtonFor` overloads : no one uses a boolean third parameter as "check button if value == something". Third parameter (when it exists) is just here for htmlAttributes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830415%28v=vs.108%29

If your firstLine works, it's just because you use `1` as second parameter (`Model.LivStato == 1` doesn't do anything).

You may try (untested)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, 1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, -1)
```

and change -1 to null in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, null)` don't work. I put `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, -1)` and in my Controller I change -1 in null.

Answer (score 7):

**Updated answer**

Oops, my original answer did not work if the *null* radio button was not first in the list. As noted by @sohtimsso1970, the radio button would have a checked attribute which would normally cause it to be selected even when the value is not null *unless there was another checked radio button later down in the DOM*, which of course there would be if the true/false-bound radio button came below null-bound one.

With this in mind, here's a better solution:

```
@{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (!Model.LivStato.HasValue) { dict.Add("checked", "checked"); }
}
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, "", dict) Null</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, 1) +1</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, -1) -1</label>
```

This will work regardless of where the null-bound radio button is on the DOM and also renders the correct HTML.

---

**Original answer:**

Using the following radio button will bind to *null*:

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, "", new { @checked = !Model.LiveStato.HasValue }) %>
```

The `checked` attribute is required so the radio button is correctly checked when the ViewModel property is null.

Comment: can also use `new { @checked = Model.LiveStato == null }`

Comment: This does not work.  This will make it so the input radio is selected no matter if Model.LiveStato has a value or not.  The HTML that is rendered is `<input type="radio" checked="False"/>` which produces the exact same result as `<input type="radio" checked="True"/>`.  The `checked` attribute in HTML does not care what value is entered (true or false).  The presence of the attribute alone with cause the element to be selected.

Comment: @sohtimsso1970 - Heh, of course - thanks for commenting. When testing this I ordered the radio buttons Null, True, False. In this case in works as the last checked radio button will be displayed as selected (and is also bound correctly in MVC). I've since updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice, +1 restored!  I hadn't considered the dictionary method

Comment: Simpler is to combine the two: ```Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LivStato, "", !Model.LiveStato.HasValue ? new { @checked = "checked" } : null)``` -- that way you don't render the checked attribute, but you can do it inline instead of a separate code block.